# How to copy in bash all directory and files recursive?

Tags: bash, copy, directory

I have script:

```
find ./SourceFolder/ -maxdepth 4 -exec cp -R '{}' ./DestFolder/ \;
```

`SourceDir` contains also sub-folders.

Problem that in `DestFolder` not only all tree, but in up level all another levels and files.

How to fix ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add -name "*.txt"

Comment: You should add the missing info to your question, by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055501/5411817)

Answer (score 426, accepted):

```
cp -r ./SourceFolder ./DestFolder
```

Comment: So, to clarify, capital -R option will copy the root dir again; small -r option keeps the root paths the same.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile - from my tests just now and according to the man pages, -r and -R don't differ.

Comment: @aaaaaa, ty! which OS/version are you on? I found out later it seems that bash commands can differ subtly across operating systems.

Comment: `cp` is not a bash command but a separate executable, so it is system-specific. True bash commands on the other hand are the same across operating systems.

Comment: I had to add a slash at the end of my source folder.  Not sure why.  I was using build vars too.

    `cp -r "$CONFIG_PATH/" "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"`

Comment: Will this not create `SourceFolder` _in_ `DestFolder`?

Answer (score 75):

code for a simple copy.

```
cp -r ./SourceFolder ./DestFolder
```

code for a copy with success result

```
cp -rv ./SourceFolder ./DestFolder
```

code for Forcefully if source contains any readonly file it will also copy

```
cp -rf ./SourceFolder ./DestFolder
```

for details help

```
cp --help
```

Answer (score 14):

also try this `cp -r ./dist/* ./out`;

this command will copy `dist/*` files to `out` dir;

Comment: @SherylHohman It's different because he put a /* on the end of the source folder. I don't know why that matters though.

Comment: this response instead of copying the entire folder copies content of the source folder into the destination (./out) folder

Answer (score 5):

You might find it handy to keep your attributes set

`cp -arf ./SourceFolder ./DestFolder`

Comment: `cp -arf ...` throws the error "cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together." Changing it to `cp -af ...` solves it. I'm not sure if it's a typo on your end of if `cp -arf ...` actually worked for you, but I hope this helps in case anyone is getting the same error. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32695418/5810737