# Unix Terminal error - "cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together."

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, cp

I have bash script running on os-x unix with above command:

`cp -avr source destination`

The result is following error:

`cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together.`

When I remove the `a` flag it works OK without errors.

Why and what is the meaning of this error?

Thanks,

Comment: @KurzedMetal I don't understand your comment

Comment: @michael - what he/she meant is that you will find an answer to your question in the documentation - in the manual to be exact. If you type in "man cp" in shell, you'll see description to all the switches `cp` accepts. It's a wise thing to do - to first read manual before asking question. RTFM itself means "read the f*** manual", but don't be offended by it, it's a common phrase, we've all heard it few times :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at man page for `cp`:

> -a, --archive
>     same as -d**R** --preserve=all
>
> **-R, -r**, --recursive
>     copy directories recursively

So by specifying `-a`, you basically say:

```
cp -dRvr --preserve=all source destination
```

You have both `-R` and `-r`, and since those two are same, it warns you. To fix that, just remove `-r`:

```
cp -av source destination
```

Comment: But I need the r for recursive

Comment: @michael - when you specify `-a`, it already means `cp` will operate recursively.