# Automating generation of React native app apk

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, expo, build-automation

I have 1 React native webview app.

I would like to produce X amount of WebView apps with that 1 app. Everything will be the same apart from the initial brand url and brand logos.

So i would like to write a script that calls react-native new brandName and then copies all the files from the first react native app with the correct brand and brandURL variables. (I think this is possible ?)

which platform i should use to develop this in ubuntu, i thought fastlane would be a good option but it is not working in ubuntu 18.04 and i want to this task.

Comment: Can you use GULP Script? You can use it copy files generate Android APK etc, if you need product flavours you can also use react-native-config library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible. Use bash to write a script to do exactly what you just said.

Comment: how can you show me an example? which does the exactly this kind of work

Comment: if you are new to bash check this out, https://medium.com/@aashish.y2z/making-a-simple-bash-script-ae2171e90ccf

after knowing a few bash skills you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055501/how-to-copy-in-bash-all-directory-and-files-recursive