# Copy files from nested directories to similar nested directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have files under nested directories like 
/x/0/0/0/a.txt till /x/9/9/9/a.txt
To be more specific
Under /x/ there are 0-9 folders 
Under /x/0/ there are 0-9 folders 
Under /x/0/0/ there are 0-9 folders 
Under/x/0/0/0/ there are files like a b c.

Now all these files needed to be copied to a directory like
/y/ , where the previous directory structure should be followed.

Comment: What have you tried ? What is not working ? what does similar mean in this context ? identical or transformed in some way. All the files or just some of them ?

Comment: [man 1 cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)?? The `-a` option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy in bash all directory and files recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055501/how-to-copy-in-bash-all-directory-and-files-recursive)

Comment: What is the final file name in /y/?

Answer (score 1):

Basically simplest "cp -r" is doing this task;

If you need to copy directory including "x"

```
cp -r /x /y/
```

Otherwise if you need only folders inside of "x"

```
cp -rp /x/* /y/
```